# Pandas transform: assign result to each element of group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-structures

I am currently using pandas groupby and transform to calculate smth for each group (once) and then assign the result to each row of the group.
If the result of calculations is scalar it can be obtained like:

```
df['some_col'] = df.groupby('id')['some_col'].transform(lambda x:process(x))
```

The problem is that the result of my calculations is **vector**, and pd tries to make element-wise assignment of result vector to the group (quote from [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)):

> The transform function must:
>   Return a result that is either the same size as the group chunk or broadcastable to the size of the group chunk (e.g., a scalar, grouped.transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])).

I could hardcode external function, creating a group-sized list, that will contain copies of result  (currently on python 3.6, so it's not possible to use assignment inside lambda):

```
def return_group(x):
    result = process(x)
    return [result for item in x]
```

But I think that it's possible to solve this somehow "smarter". Remember that it's **necessary to make calculations only once** for each group.

Is it possible to force pd.transform work with array-like result of lambda function like with scalars (just copy it n-times)?

Would be grateful for any advices.

P. S. I understand, that it's possible to use combination of apply and join to solve the original requirement, but the solution with transform has more priority in my case.

Comment: Do you mean the output of the `lambda` inside your transform return a vector for each row or a different size vector than the number of rows in the group?

Comment: It calculates one vector, that should be the result for each element of group. The size of this vector is fixed (and independent of group len).

Comment: You don't care what rows of the group the resulting vector will get assigned to. For example the resulting vector is of size 3 and the group is of size 30 rows, is it OK if the 3 values get assigned to the first 3 or last 3 or random 3 rows of the group?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime transform is a pain to work with If that's not a problem for you I'd suggest you to use `groupby` + a `left` `pd.merge` as in this example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,2,2,2],
                   "col":[1,2,3,4,5]})

# this return a list for every group
grp = df.groupby("id")["col"]\
        .apply(lambda x: list(x))\
        .reset_index(name="out")

#  Then you merge it to the original df
df = pd.merge(df, grp, how="left")
```

And `print(df)` returns

```sh
   id  col        out
0   1    1     [1, 2]
1   1    2     [1, 2]
2   2    3  [3, 4, 5]
3   2    4  [3, 4, 5]
4   2    5  [3, 4, 5]
```